# Read / Watch / Listen times - meta

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I have a website organised around three kinds of posts (categorised accordingly): "Read" "Watch" and "Listen".

I want to have a *read-time* and *watch-time* and *listen-time* aligned with each respective post category. My theme uses powerkit for the *read-time*, so really I'm looking for a way to add the *"Watch"* and *"Listen"* times over the top of WP's default *read-time*. I'm happy to do this manually with each post.

There are some plugins, I think, but is it possible to just use a custom css specific to a post to override the text of the default read-time with my watch/listen time? I'd need this for both the post, and the archive post/list views, etc.

Site is here:
https://drcdeane.com

```
.cs-entry__post-meta .cs-meta-reading-time {
  display: ??????
}
```